# Android app upgrade with a different appid

Tags: android

Our Android app will be taken over by a different company. This requires that the app-id/package-id be changed (from com.mycompany.app to com.newcompany.app). However, when a newer version of the apk is installed, it gets installed as a separate application as the app-ids don't match. Wondering if there is any hint we can add to the manifest indicating that the current version is an upgrade for the specific app-id. Guessing this would be a common problem for any company that acquires Android software product from another company. Regards.

Comment: Don't think you can change pck name. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename  In bold you can never change it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do to get one app (com.package.appA) to upgrade(via app store) to another app (com.package.appB).

That said, you don't really have to change the package name to transfer the app. Most users aren't aware of the package name of the app they install so it won't really buy you any credibility.

What you would have to do is provide the new company is the release signing key for your application. They are going to need this to upload new versions of the app to the play store. Hopefully you have just one for this app.

Tips for the future if you're planning on transferring more apps:

1. Use more generic package names (com.mysite.calculator vs apps.calculator). Package names are just identifiers so use them as such.
2. Use a single signing key per project so that you can give it away with the code and won't expose all your other apps.

Answer (score 0):

If your Gradle file specifies an application ID:

- You can go ahead and change the app's *package name*. (However, this would require a lot of updates to the app's source code, since the generated `R` class will end up with a new package name. Also, the package name used to resolve relative class names in the manifest would change.)
- But, you must keep the same application ID if you want Android to consider the result to be the same app. Furthermore, you must keep using the same signing certificate as well!